# GWT: Building widgets with separated mvp

Tags: java, design-patterns, gwt, widget, mvp

I'm trying to build a gwt widget with separated model, view and presenter.

I'm using just one class for all of these components so far:

A compact example:

```
public class MyCellSelectableTable extends Composite {

   private WhatEverRepresentation selectedCell;

   public MyCellSelectableTable() {

      Grid myTable = new Grid(2,2);
      /*
       * Some code to realize a table with cell selection
       * ...
       */

     initWidget(myTable);
  }
}
```

In my appreciation the information "selectedCell" (and in my project many other data) should be stored in a separate model. 
How can I implement this structurally correct, so it still is a widget but with an encapsulated mvp architecture?

Comment: You need to explain more as what are you trying to do. Thats like saying you need a separate MVC for a button. How ever if it really is what you are saying it is which I doubt. You can put it in a separate project with it's own gwt.xml module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my projects I was asked to design a spinner item which is dressed to look good on a mobile web app. Then we realized we actually need another view for our spinner which is 'thinner' as well. So I have tried to aplly the MVP approach to my widget implementation which worked well for me. This one below is a very simple example not for production use just for the sake of demonstration

Define a Presenter and a View interface as in MVP pattern. The point here is to make the view implementations dumb so they can be switched without a hassle. Note that Spinner is not actually a Widget but it implements IsWidget which means it will be treated like a widget but in fact we will be passing the reference of our view implementation.

```
public class Spinner implements IsWidget, SpinnerPresenter{
    interface View{
        Widget asWidget();
        void stepUp(int step);
        void stepDown(int step);
        void setValue(int value);
        void setPixelSize(int width,int height);
    }   
    View view;
    int value;  
    public Spinner() {
        view = new SpinnerImpl(this);
        view.setValue(0);
    }   
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }   
    public void setValue(int value) {
        if (value == this.value)
            return;
        this.value = value;
        view.setValue(value);
    }
    public void setPixelSize(int width, int height){
        view.setPixelSize(width,height);
    }
    @Override
    public void downButtonClicked() {
        value--;
        view.stepDown(1);
    }
    @Override
    public void upButtonClicked() {
        value++;
        view.stepUp(1);
    }
    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        return view.asWidget();
    }
}
```

And the view Implementation itself which implements the view interface defined in Spinner class. Notice how we delegate user events to Spinner class to be handled over the SpinnerPresenter interface.

```
public class SpinnerImpl extends Composite implements Spinner.View{
    private TextBox txtBox;
    private Button upButton,downButton;
    private HorizontalPanel panel;
    private SpinnerPresenter presenter;
    public SpinnerImpl(SpinnerPresenter presenter){
        this.presenter = presenter;
        upButton = new Button("up");
        downButton = new Button("down");

        txtBox = new TextBox();
        txtBox.setEnabled(false);

        panel = new HorizontalPanel();
        panel.add(upButton);
        panel.add(txtBox);
        panel.add(downButton);

        addHandlers();
        initWidget(panel);      
    }   
    private void addHandlers() {
        upButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                presenter.upButtonClicked();
            }
        });
        downButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                presenter.downButtonClicked();
            }
        });     
    }
    @Override
    public void stepDown(int step) {
        txtBox.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtBox.getValue())-1+"");
    }
    @Override
    public void stepUp(int step) {
        txtBox.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtBox.getValue())+1+"");
    }
    @Override
    public void setValue(int value) {
        txtBox.setValue(0+"");
    }
}
```

SpinnerPresenter interface :

```
public interface SpinnerPresenter {
    void upButtonClicked();
    void downButtonClicked();
}
```

Finally to add my widget to rootpanel. Notice I can add spinner class as if it was a widget

```
Spinner s = new Spinner();
RootPanel.get().add(s);
```

Now if i wanted to change the way my spinner item looks, change orientation, maybe add a fancy animation for spinning etc, I need only to change my View Implementation. Last but not least when it comes to testing my widget this approach will help since I can easily mockup my view.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read the following MVP article if you haven't already (and forgive me if you have): <strike>http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html</strike> http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html

Believe me it's worth it to go ahead and separate out your model, view, and presenter. The problem always seems simple enough to have in one class, but when I've tried that I always end up separating things out. You'll appreciate having a better separation of concerns and the flexibility it offers.

Comment: the link you provided in not found.plz update the link

Comment: Thanks, IdntKnw. I changed the link to be where the old link redirects.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the cell widgets in GWT are built with MVP internally. A `CellList` (for instance) is the "view" part and instantiates an internal presenter.

Also, this session from Google I/O 2010 was eye opening for me: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/gwt-continuous-build-testing.html